# How to place element in Navigation drawer in Android

Tags: android, xml, menu, navigation-drawer

I want to do a navigation drawer with icons and text displayed like this : [image with icon display in block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsyMH.jpg)

My navigation drawer is :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_background"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />
```

And my menu is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <!-- todo: une page d'accueil avec les plus grosse cote, une preview du bilan (cardview? ...)-->

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navItemHome"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/action_home"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navItemParisTermine"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/actionParisTermine"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navItemAffiliation"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/actionAffiliation"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navItemBilan"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/actionBilan"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navItemContactDeveloppeur"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/actionContactDeveloppeur"/>

    </group>


</menu>
```

Sorry for my english and thanks for your attention!

Comment: what's not working in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a menu in your navigation drawer, create a custom layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  // CREATE YOUR LAYOUT HERE 

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope you got it.
Don't worry about your English, no one should make fun when someone is learning a new language, it just means they know another one

Answer (score 1):

Menu is quite limited on customization. In this case you would probably need to get rid of menu at all. 
To do this remove this line:

```
  app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items"
```

You can rely on navigation drawer header and implement custom view with icons as you show in example.
Your Navigation View has this line:

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
```

So go to `navigation_drawer_header` and apply custom layout to it.